# Начать поиск пикселя снизу заданной области

Tags: python

Пример который я использую, но он ищет сверху вниз, а как мне начать искать снизу вверх.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from mss import mss
import pyautogui as pg

monitor = {
    "left": 8,
    "top": 31,
    "width": 845,
    "height": 785,
}


# Поиск цвета на экране
def find_color(our_color, monitor={}):
    # Возмём кусок экрана
    m = mss()

    # Получаем пиксель с экрана монитора
    img = m.grab(monitor)

    # Преобразуем этот пиксель в матрицу
    img_arr = np.array(img)

    # Поиск цвета (b, g, r, alpha)
    our_map = (our_color[2], our_color[1], our_color[0], 255)
    indexes = np.where(np.all(img_arr == our_map, axis=-1))
    our_crd = np.transpose(indexes)
    return our_crd


# Искомый цвет
our_color = [200, 144, 104]

while True:
    time1 = time.time()
    result = find_color(our_color, monitor)
    time2 = time.time()
    if result.__len__():
        x = result[0][1] + monitor.get('left')
        y = result[0][0] + monitor.get('top')
        print(time2 - time1, [x, y])
        pg.moveTo(x, y)

    # Ожидание
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Ну, наверное, взять `result[-1]` вместо `result[0]`, если я тут всё правильно понял.

Comment: ТК я не совсем понимаю, попытаюсь объяснить свои размышления, мы преобразуем пиксели нужного участка экрана в матрицу каждого пикселя и потом просто перебираем,  а можно ли перебор матриц начать с конца?

Comment: Так тут нет перебора, тут сразу все строки обрабатываются. Я просто предлагаю вам не первый элемент из результата взять, а последний. Не факт, что так точно сработает, но я бы попробовал.